# How to set Bootstrap @font-family-base?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, font-face

[Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview) say:

> Use the `@font-family-base`, `@font-size-base`, and `@line-height-base` attributes as our typographic base.

Does this mean there is a CSS variable called `@font-family-base`?

How can I set this in CSS to change the font for my whole page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visit [the Bootstrap docs on customization](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) - you can change several variables in Typography section, for instance `@sansFontFamily`, `@serifFontFamily`, `@monoFontFamily`, `@baseFontSize`, etc

Comment: @cja Until RC2, the Bootstrap 3 customizer will be disabled. In the mean time, snag the compiled CSS and JavaScript. Hang tight!

Comment: I noticed. Anyway, I have the compiled files on my computer. Surely I can change them to effect the font I want?

Answer (score 26):

For Bootstrap 3 open up your custom.css and

```
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6 {
    font-family: "Ubuntu", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
}
```

Comment: It sucks that this is the only way I could get it to work, but - it was - greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 16):

It's not a CSS variable, it's a [LESS variable](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less-variables).

You can find (and edit) them in [`variables.less`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/08cd3072fc48d8b4ad7e9062cd5e9bbea1cc19da/less/variables.less).

Comment: There is no less directory in my Bootstrap download folder. (I got the latest version a few days ago.)

Comment: Possibly because I have v3

Comment: That's because you have the compiled CSS files. You can download the LESS files and use them, or fiddle around with the compiled ones if you prefer

Comment: Just to give some updated info on "CSS has no variables at all" CSS has a WIP spec for variables http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/

Answer (score 0):

See below, place at the top of your CSS file.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
```